# Material datepicker format change W/O moments

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

Is there a way to format mat datepicker without the commonly used moment/moments-adapter method that's found on almost everywhere. This would be a niche use-case (one time only) in our app and i'd rather not add a dependency for it.

I'd like to achieve to limit (user should be able to pick year only / this functionality is easily achievable/) and display years only.
We use reactive forms so no ngModel binding!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way i think you can achieve only year selection, is by settings the start-view and listen to the year selected output.

```
<mat-datepicker #datepicker [startView]="multi-year" 
(yearSelected)="datepicker.close();yearSelected($event)">

</mat-datepicker>

Typecript:
public yearSelected(year: number): void {
 // push value to your form here
}
```

Sorry if i missunderstood your question i did not understand what you mean with formatting

Comment: In format i meant the date the datepicker displays the selected date.
eg.: 01.06.2020, I only want the year to be displayed